# How can I make a link to the actual ID of the profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to provide a link for my users to view others' profiles. I want it to be by ID. I have this line:

```
<a href=""><%= link_to post.author.username, profile_path(post.author) %></a>
```

I can't link directly to the ID of the post. Instead, I have to use user_id. I get this error:

```
undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's your other code? This error seems not related to the line you showed.

Comment: If error related your line, looks like you haven't post object. Maybe @post instead of post? Also, you don't need <a href=""> around link_to.

Comment: @Mahys116 if `post` was nil then `post.author` would raise a different error ...

Comment: can you please show the stack trace of the error - what file/line is it coming from?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301499/how-can-i-link-to-the-actual-id-of-the-profile#comment95423325_54301499) is the same question asked. I think that's the same user.

Comment: Please provide us with more code from your view file. It looks as though the error you are receiving is not related to the posts.* model. A different error would have been raised. Is there another model referenced in this view that is not in the controller (but should be)?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `post.author` returns `nil`. You should check first if an author exists before trying to generate a link – for example like this:

```
<%= link_to(post.author.username, profile_path(post.author)) if post.author %>
```

Or write a helper method:

```
# in a helper
def profile_link(user)
  link_to(user.username, profile_path(user)) if user
end

# in the view
<%= profile_link(post.author) %>
```

Btw: `link_to` returns a `a` HTML tag, there is no need for an additional `<a href="">...</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have an issue while saving your `post` and you don't set author as well so `post.author` is `nil`.

As @spickermann said you should put a guard to check if `post.author` exists, and if doesn't you can display some generic message.

Something like this:

```
<% if post.author %>
   <%= link_to(post.author.username, profile_path(post.author)) %>
<% else %>
   "Unknown author"
<% end %>
```